# How to get the Telegram bot username in Java?

Tags: java, telegram, telegram-bot

I know how to get the username of a user that send an update or message to my bot but how can I get the username and/or name of my bot without resorting to BotFather?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I get the username and/or name of my bot

The [Telegram Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) provides a `getMe` method that:

> A simple method for testing your bot's authentication token. Requires no parameters. **Returns basic information about the bot in form of a [User](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#user) object**.

---

So, if you'd send a request like:

```
api.telegram.org/bot<MY-BOT-TOKEN>/getMe
```

You'll get the following response:

```json
{
    "ok": true,
    "result": {
        "id": 12346798,
        "is_bot": true,
        "first_name": "my_test_bot",
        "username": "my_test_bot",
        "can_join_groups": true,
        "can_read_all_group_messages": false,
        "supports_inline_queries": false
    }
}
```